# Get particular row of tableView item which has some condition (JavaFX)

Tags: java, uitableview, javafx, row

I am making attendance TableView for one person. I am getting tableView row and if person in that specific day has status "present" (string) then I want to change that **particular** row and change its background-color to green.

Then if he is "absent" in that **particular** day I want to change that row and set red background.

Otherwise if there is no date and status in row I need to change row again and set white background.

PROBLEM: It is going through first **if** statement and then set every row green because first statement is "true".

I want to get only rows with present and set only that rows to green background colour.

*getStatus returns String

```
studentTable.setRowFactory(tableView -> {
    final TableRow<Attendance> row = new TableRow<>();

        for (Attendance item : studentTable.getItems()) {
            if (item.getStatus().equals("present")) {
                row.setStyle("-fx-background-color:green;");
            }
            else if (item.getStatus().equals("absent")){
                row.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red;");
            }
            else {
                row.setStyle("-fx-background-color:white;");
            }
        }
return row;
    });
}
```

PICTURE WITH RESULT: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGB1T.png)

I will be thankful for any solution and any help :)

Comment: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your code does is create a `TableRow` when needed, and then each time a `TableRow` is created, it iterates over *all* the items in the table, continually changing the style of that *one single row*. So the row will simply have the style determined by the last item in the table's items list (because that item determines the final call to `setStyle(...)`). And of course, you do this for every row you create, so unsurprisingly every row has the same style.

The `TableRow`'s `updateItem(...)` method is called when the row is first used to display an `Attendance` instance, and again any time the row is reused to display a different `Attendance` instance. Thus you need to override `updateItem()` and place the logic there.

```
studentTable.setRowFactory(tableView -> new TableRow<Attendance>() {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Attendance attendance, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(attendance, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setStyle("");
        } else if (attendance.getStatus().equals("present")) {
            setStyle("-fx-background-color:green;");
        } else if (attendance.getStatus().equals("absent")) {
            setStyle("-fx-background-color:red;");
        } else {
            setStyle("-fx-background-color:white;");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry James but I am still beginner, can you please edit your code in way that I can implement it? :/ With my for-each loop or row field. I tried but I think I cannot do it. Thank you very much for your help and time.

Comment: @MapeSVK What's wrong with the code I posted? You can't do this with a loop, because there's no collection of `TableRow`s to iterate through. Typically there isn't even a `TableRow` instance for every item in the table (that's kind of the entire point of a table view in the first place)

Comment: I don't know where to put it. I just had "item" field which was part of the for-each loop and also "row" field which was name of row in tableView. Now you are using these two words without declaration of these fields first.

Comment: @MapeSVK Ah, I see. I had copied some of your code and not updated it to match the parts I put in. That should work now.

Comment: Thank you James! Now I also understand how it works.